# Ckeditor and reactjs, this.getselection is null

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, reactjs, react-router

I'm using CKEditor with my project and im trying to prefill the textarea with data im getting from the server, that way it is easier for a user to edit. I do so in this component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link,State, Route} from 'react-router';
import Router from 'react-router';
import ReportsActions from 'actions/ReportsActions';
import ReportsStore from 'stores/ReportsStore';
import $ from 'jquery';

export default class EditReport extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = ReportsStore.getState();
  this.state.singleReport = [];
  this.state.editReport = [];
  this.state.link = window.location.href;
    }

componentDidMount() {
  let state = this.state.link;
  state = state.split('/');
  state = state[state.length-2];
  ReportsActions.getSoloReport(state);
  ReportsStore.listen(this._onChanges);
 CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckedit', {
  allowedContent : true,      
  pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles : false,
  pasteFromWordRemoveStyles : false
  });
  console.log(this.state.editReport);
 }
componentWillUnmount() {
  ReportsStore.unlisten(this._onChanges);
    }

_onChanges = () => {
  this.setState({
      singleReport: ReportsStore.getState().singleReport,
      duplicate: ReportsStore.getState().singleReport,
      editReport: ReportsStore.getState().editReport
    });
}

_onCreateReport = () => {
  for ( var instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();

  let state = this.state.link;
  state = state.split('/');
  state = state[state.length-2];
  const title = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.title).value;
  const date = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.date).value;
  const body = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.body).value;
  const id = state;
  ReportsActions.editReport({
        title: title,
        date: date,
        body: body,
        id: id
    });
}

render() {
  let singleReport = this.state.singleReport;
  let editReport = this.state.editReport;
  let ckbody = "fetching data..";
  if(ckbody == undefined) {
     ckbody = "Fetching data..";
  }
  else {
    ckbody = editReport.body;
   }

 let state = this.state.link;
 if(CKEDITOR.instances['ckedit'] == undefined) {
    console.log('not defined');
 }
  else {
    console.log(CKEDITOR.instances['ckedit'].getData());
    CKEDITOR.instances['ckedit'].setData(ckbody);
  }
  state = state.split('/');
  state = state[state.length-2];
  return(
    <div>
    <main>
    <h1>Hello im trying to edit</h1>
    <fieldset className = "fieldSet2">
          <input type = "text" placeholder = {editReport.title} ref = "title"/>
          <input type = "text" placeholder = {editReport.date} ref = "date"/>
          <textarea className = "ckeditor" id = "ckedit" ref = "body" name = "ckedit" defaultValue = {editReport.body}>{editReport.body}</textarea>
          <Link to= "singlereports" params ={{id: state}}><button type="submit" rows = "5" cols = "5" className ="superButton" onClick={this._onCreateReport}>Edit Report</button></Link>
          </fieldset>
          <div className ="toMyEmployees2">
        <div className="containers1">
  <div className="spacer">
   <Link to="AllEmployees">
    <a className="wide blue">
    <i className="fa fa-users"></i>
      <h2>View All Employees</h2>
    </a>
    </Link>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div className ="toMyEmployees3">
        <div className="containers1">
  <div className="spacer">
   <Link to="dashboard">
    <a className="wide redgay">
    <i className="fa fa-tachometer"></i>
      <h2>Dashboard</h2>
    </a>
    </Link>
    </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    </div>
    );

}
}
```

I've set CKEditor and initialized it in ComponentDidMount, then in render I try to setHTML to one of my states. When I first visit the component the editor displays the data inside it that I wan't to edit, however if I hit the back button or any other link/route and return to the editor, it spits out 'cannot read property of getSelection of undefined', tracing it, it belongs to this.document.getWindow. This is a single page app as well. I don't know why it's doing this, but maybe I have to remove the instance as well?